# Why do I have to restart the network service every time I turn on CentOS?

Tags: centos, networking

I have a CentOS system which I use as a SSH server and it works fine; I can even SSH from outside the LAN. My problem is that the CentOS seem to be "unreachable" (even from within the LAN) every time I turn it on, but after a `service network restart` it returns to normal, so basically I have to `service network restart` every time I turn off and turn on the server -- why is this happening?

This is the configuration I have:

**/etc/sysconfig/network**:

[image]

**/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0**:

[image]

The command:

```
sudo chkconfig --list network
```

returns:

```
network 0:off 1:off 2:on 3:on 4:on 5:on 6:off
```

The output of:

```
dmesg
```

is:

```
Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
Linux version 2.6.32-642.el6.i686 (mockbuild@worker1.bsys.centos.org) (gcc versi                                                                                        on 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Tue May 10 16:13:51 UTC 2016
KERNEL supported cpus:
  Intel GenuineIntel
  AMD AuthenticAMD
  NSC Geode by NSC
  Cyrix CyrixInstead
  Centaur CentaurHauls
  Transmeta GenuineTMx86
  Transmeta TransmetaCPU
  UMC UMC UMC UMC
BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
 BIOS-e820: 0000000000000000 - 000000000009fc00 (usable)
 BIOS-e820: 000000000009fc00 - 00000000000a0000 (reserved)
 BIOS-e820: 00000000000f0000 - 0000000000100000 (reserved)
 BIOS-e820: 0000000000100000 - 000000006b7f0000 (usable)
 BIOS-e820: 000000006b7f0000 - 000000006b800000 (ACPI data)
 BIOS-e820: 00000000fec00000 - 00000000fec01000 (reserved)
 BIOS-e820: 00000000fee00000 - 00000000fee01000 (reserved)
 BIOS-e820: 00000000fffc0000 - 0000000100000000 (reserved)
SMBIOS version 2.5 @ 0xFFF60
SMBIOS 2.5 present.
DMI: innotek GmbH VirtualBox/VirtualBox, BIOS VirtualBox 12/01/2006
Hypervisor detected: KVM
e820 update range: 0000000000000000 - 0000000000001000 (usable) ==> (reserved)
e820 remove range: 00000000000a0000 - 0000000000100000 (usable)
last_pfn = 0x6b7f0 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000
x86 PAT enabled: cpu 0, old 0x7040600070406, new 0x7010600070106
CPU MTRRs all blank - virtualized system.
initial memory mapped : 0 - 01000000
init_memory_mapping: 0000000000000000-00000000375fe000
Using x86 segment limits to approximate NX protection
 0000000000 - 0000200000 page 4k
 0000200000 - 0037400000 page 2M
 0037400000 - 00375fe000 page 4k
kernel direct mapping tables up to 375fe000 @ 7000-10000
RAMDISK: 36fbc000 - 37fefb2b
Allocated new RAMDISK: 00cd6000 - 01d09b2b
Move RAMDISK from 0000000036fbc000 - 0000000037fefb2a to 00cd6000 - 01d09b2a
ACPI: Deleted _OSI()
ACPI: Deleted _OSI()
ACPI: RSDP 000e0000 00024 (v02 VBOX  )
ACPI: XSDT 6b7f0030 00034 (v01 VBOX   VBOXXSDT 00000001 ASL  00000061)
ACPI: FACP 6b7f00f0 000F4 (v04 VBOX   VBOXFACP 00000001 ASL  00000061)
ACPI: DSDT 6b7f0410 0210F (v01 VBOX   VBOXBIOS 00000002 INTL 20100528)
ACPI: FACS 6b7f0200 00040
ACPI: SSDT 6b7f0240 001CC (v01 VBOX   VBOXCPUT 00000002 INTL 20100528)
833MB HIGHMEM available.
885MB LOWMEM available.
  mapped low ram: 0 - 375fe000
  low ram: 0 - 375fe000
  node 0 low ram: 00000000 - 375fe000
  node 0 bootmap 0000b000 - 00011ec0
(9 early reservations) ==> bootmem [0000000000 - 00375fe000]
  #0 [0000000000 - 0000001000]   BIOS data page ==> [0000000000 - 0000001000]
  #1 [0000001000 - 0000002000]    EX TRAMPOLINE ==> [0000001000 - 0000002000]
  #2 [0000006000 - 0000007000]       TRAMPOLINE ==> [0000006000 - 0000007000]
  #3 [0000400000 - 0000ccc090]    TEXT DATA BSS ==> [0000400000 - 0000ccc090]
  #4 [000009f800 - 0000100000]    BIOS reserved ==> [000009f800 - 0000100000]
  #5 [0000ccd000 - 0000cd5114]              BRK ==> [0000ccd000 - 0000cd5114]
  #6 [0000007000 - 000000b000]          PGTABLE ==> [0000007000 - 000000b000]
  #7 [0000cd6000 - 0001d09b2b]      NEW RAMDISK ==> [0000cd6000 - 0001d09b2b]
  #8 [000000b000 - 0000012000]          BOOTMAP ==> [000000b000 - 0000012000]
crashkernel=auto resulted in zero bytes of reserved memory.
kvm-clock: Using msrs 4b564d01 and 4b564d00
kvm-clock: cpu 0, msr 0:b99ae1, boot clock
Zone PFN ranges:
  DMA      0x00000001 -> 0x00001000
  Normal   0x00001000 -> 0x000375fe
  HighMem  0x000375fe -> 0x0006b7f0
Movable zone start PFN for each node
early_node_map[2] active PFN ranges
    0: 0x00000001 -> 0x0000009f
    0: 0x00000100 -> 0x0006b7f0
On node 0 totalpages: 440206
  DMA zone: 32 pages used for memmap
  DMA zone: 0 pages reserved
  DMA zone: 3966 pages, LIFO batch:0
  Normal zone: 1740 pages used for memmap
  Normal zone: 220978 pages, LIFO batch:31
  HighMem zone: 1668 pages used for memmap
  HighMem zone: 211822 pages, LIFO batch:31
Using APIC driver default
ACPI: PM-Timer IO Port: 0x4008
SMP: Allowing 1 CPUs, 0 hotplug CPUs
Found and enabled local APIC!
nr_irqs_gsi: 16
PM: Registered nosave memory: 000000000009f000 - 00000000000a0000
PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000000a0000 - 00000000000f0000
PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000000f0000 - 0000000000100000
Allocating PCI resources starting at 6b800000 (gap: 6b800000:93400000)
Booting paravirtualized kernel on KVM
NR_CPUS:32 nr_cpumask_bits:32 nr_cpu_ids:1 nr_node_ids:1
PERCPU: Embedded 16 pages/cpu @c2e00000 s41240 r0 d24296 u2097152
pcpu-alloc: s41240 r0 d24296 u2097152 alloc=1*2097152
pcpu-alloc: [0] 0
kvm-clock: cpu 0, msr 0:2e09ae1, primary cpu clock
Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 436766
Kernel command line: ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_vmcentos-lv_root rd_NO_LUKS LANG=en_                                                                                        US.UTF-8 rd_LVM_LV=vg_vmcentos/lv_swap rd_NO_MD SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 rd_LVM                                                                                        _LV=vg_vmcentos/lv_root   KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet
PID hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
Dentry cache hash table entries: 131072 (order: 7, 524288 bytes)
Inode-cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
Enabling fast FPU save and restore... done.
Enabling unmasked SIMD FPU exception support... done.
Initializing CPU#0
Initializing HighMem for node 0 (000375fe:0006b7f0)
Memory: 1716812k/1761216k available (4614k kernel code, 43080k reserved, 2613k d                                                                                        ata, 556k init, 853960k highmem)
virtual kernel memory layout:
    fixmap  : 0xffad5000 - 0xfffff000   (5288 kB)
    pkmap   : 0xff600000 - 0xff800000   (2048 kB)
    vmalloc : 0xf7dfe000 - 0xff5fe000   ( 120 MB)
    lowmem  : 0xc0000000 - 0xf75fe000   ( 885 MB)
      .init : 0xc0b10000 - 0xc0b9b000   ( 556 kB)
      .data : 0xc0881a78 - 0xc0b0f228   (2613 kB)
      .text : 0xc0400000 - 0xc0881a78   (4614 kB)
Checking if this processor honours the WP bit even in supervisor mode...Ok.
Hierarchical RCU implementation.
NR_IRQS:2304 nr_irqs:256
Console: colour VGA+ 80x25
console [tty0] enabled
allocated 4194304 bytes of page_cgroup
please try 'cgroup_disable=memory' option if you don't want memory cgroups
Detected 2133.786 MHz processor.
Calibrating delay loop (skipped) preset value.. 4267.57 BogoMIPS (lpj=2133786)
pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
Security Framework initialized
SELinux:  Initializing.
SELinux:  Starting in permissive mode
Mount-cache hash table entries: 512
Initializing cgroup subsys ns
Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
Initializing cgroup subsys memory
Initializing cgroup subsys devices
Initializing cgroup subsys freezer
Initializing cgroup subsys net_cls
Initializing cgroup subsys blkio
Initializing cgroup subsys perf_event
Initializing cgroup subsys net_prio
CPU: Physical Processor ID: 0
mce: CPU supports 0 MCE banks
using mwait in idle threads.
alternatives: switching to unfair spinlock
SMP alternatives: switching to UP code
Freeing SMP alternatives: 18k freed
ACPI: Core revision 20090903
ACPI: setting ELCR to 0200 (from 0e00)
weird, boot CPU (#0) not listed by the BIOS.
SMP motherboard not detected.
Enabling APIC mode:  Flat.  Using 0 I/O APICs
SMP disabled
Performance Events: unsupported p6 CPU model 37 no PMU driver, software events o                                                                                        nly.
Brought up 1 CPUs
Total of 1 processors activated (4267.57 BogoMIPS).
sizeof(vma)=100 bytes
sizeof(page)=32 bytes
sizeof(inode)=352 bytes
sizeof(dentry)=132 bytes
sizeof(ext3inode)=508 bytes
sizeof(buffer_head)=56 bytes
sizeof(skbuff)=184 bytes
sizeof(task_struct)=1360 bytes
devtmpfs: initialized
regulator: core version 0.5
NET: Registered protocol family 16
ACPI: bus type pci registered
PCI: PCI BIOS revision 2.10 entry at 0xfda26, last bus=0
PCI: Using configuration type 1 for base access
bio: create slab <bio-0> at 0
ACPI: EC: Look up EC in DSDT
ACPI: Executed 1 blocks of module-level executable AML code
ACPI: Interpreter enabled
ACPI: (supports S0 S5)
ACPI: Using PIC for interrupt routing
ACPI: No dock devices found.
PCI: Ignoring host bridge windows from ACPI; if necessary, use "pci=use_crs" and                                                                                         report a bug
ACPI: PCI Root Bridge [PCI0] (domain 0000 [bus 00-ff])
pci_root PNP0A03:00: host bridge window [io  0x0000-0x0cf7] (ignored)
pci_root PNP0A03:00: host bridge window [io  0x0d00-0xffff] (ignored)
pci_root PNP0A03:00: host bridge window [mem 0x000a0000-0x000bffff] (ignored)
pci_root PNP0A03:00: host bridge window [mem 0x6b800000-0xffdfffff] (ignored)
PCI: root bus 00: using default resources
PCI host bridge to bus 0000:00
pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [io  0x0000-0xffff]
pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x00000000-0xfffffffff]
pci 0000:00:01.1: reg 20: [io  0xd000-0xd00f]
pci 0000:00:02.0: reg 10: [mem 0xe0000000-0xe0ffffff pref]
pci 0000:00:03.0: reg 10: [mem 0xf0000000-0xf001ffff]
pci 0000:00:03.0: reg 18: [io  0xd010-0xd017]
pci 0000:00:04.0: reg 10: [io  0xd020-0xd03f]
pci 0000:00:04.0: reg 14: [mem 0xf0400000-0xf07fffff]
pci 0000:00:04.0: reg 18: [mem 0xf0800000-0xf0803fff pref]
pci 0000:00:05.0: reg 10: [io  0xd100-0xd1ff]
pci 0000:00:05.0: reg 14: [io  0xd200-0xd23f]
pci 0000:00:06.0: reg 10: [mem 0xf0804000-0xf0804fff]
pci 0000:00:07.0: quirk: [io  0x4000-0x403f] claimed by PIIX4 ACPI
pci 0000:00:07.0: quirk: [io  0x4100-0x410f] claimed by PIIX4 SMB
pci 0000:00:0d.0: reg 10: [io  0xd240-0xd247]
pci 0000:00:0d.0: reg 18: [io  0xd250-0xd257]
pci 0000:00:0d.0: reg 20: [io  0xd260-0xd26f]
pci 0000:00:0d.0: reg 24: [mem 0xf0806000-0xf0807fff]
pci_bus 0000:00: on NUMA node 0
ACPI: PCI Interrupt Routing Table [\_SB_.PCI0._PRT]
ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKA] (IRQs 5 9 10 *11)
ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKB] (IRQs 5 9 10 *11)
ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKC] (IRQs 5 9 *10 11)
ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKD] (IRQs 5 *9 10 11)
vgaarb: device added: PCI:0000:00:02.0,decodes=io+mem,owns=io+mem,locks=none
vgaarb: loaded
vgaarb: bridge control possible 0000:00:02.0
SCSI subsystem initialized
libata version 3.00 loaded.
usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
usbcore: registered new device driver usb
PCI: Using ACPI for IRQ routing
PCI: old code would have set cacheline size to 32 bytes, but clflush_size = 64
PCI: pci_cache_line_size set to 64 bytes
NetLabel: Initializing
NetLabel:  domain hash size = 128
NetLabel:  protocols = UNLABELED CIPSOv4
NetLabel:  unlabeled traffic allowed by default
Switching to clocksource kvm-clock
pnp: PnP ACPI init
ACPI: bus type pnp registered
pnp 00:00: [io  0x0cf8-0x0cff]
pnp 00:00: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0a03 (active)
pnp 00:01: [io  0x0060]
pnp 00:01: [io  0x0064]
pnp 00:01: [irq 1]
pnp 00:01: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0303 (active)
pnp 00:02: [io  0x0000-0x000f]
pnp 00:02: [io  0x0080-0x008f]
pnp 00:02: [io  0x00c0-0x00df]
pnp 00:02: [dma 4]
pnp 00:02: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0200 (active)
pnp 00:03: [irq 12]
pnp 00:03: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0f03 (active)
pnp: PnP ACPI: found 4 devices
ACPI: ACPI bus type pnp unregistered
pci_bus 0000:00: resource 4 [io  0x0000-0xffff]
pci_bus 0000:00: resource 5 [mem 0x00000000-0xfffffffff]
NET: Registered protocol family 2
IP route cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
TCP established hash table entries: 131072 (order: 8, 1048576 bytes)
TCP bind hash table entries: 65536 (order: 7, 524288 bytes)
TCP: Hash tables configured (established 131072 bind 65536)
TCP reno registered
NET: Registered protocol family 1
pci 0000:00:00.0: Limiting direct PCI/PCI transfers
pci 0000:00:01.0: Activating ISA DMA hang workarounds
pci 0000:00:02.0: Boot video device
ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKB] enabled at IRQ 11
PCI: setting IRQ 11 as level-triggered
pci 0000:00:06.0: PCI INT A -> Link[LNKB] -> GSI 11 (level, low) -> IRQ 11
pci 0000:00:06.0: PCI INT A disabled
Trying to unpack rootfs image as initramfs...
Freeing initrd memory: 16590k freed
platform rtc_cmos: registered platform RTC device (no PNP device found)
apm: BIOS version 1.2 Flags 0x03 (Driver version 1.16ac)
apm: overridden by ACPI.
futex hash table entries: 256 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
audit: initializing netlink socket (disabled)
type=2000 audit(1478992613.593:1): initialized
highmem bounce pool size: 64 pages
HugeTLB registered 2 MB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.5.2
Dquot-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
msgmni has been set to 1719
SELinux:  Registering netfilter hooks
ksign: Installing public key data
Loading keyring
- Added public key 524E631171D1C9A6
- User ID: CentOS (Kernel Module GPG key)
Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 250)
io scheduler noop registered
io scheduler anticipatory registered
io scheduler deadline registered
io scheduler cfq registered (default)
pci_hotplug: PCI Hot Plug PCI Core version: 0.5
pciehp: PCI Express Hot Plug Controller Driver version: 0.4
acpiphp: ACPI Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.5
ACPI: AC Adapter [AC] (on-line)
input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input0
ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
input: Sleep Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSLPBN:00/input/input1
ACPI: Sleep Button [SLPF]
ACPI: acpi_idle registered with cpuidle
[Firmware Bug]: No valid trip found
GHES: HEST is not enabled!
isapnp: Scanning for PnP cards...
ACPI: Battery Slot [BAT0] (battery present)
isapnp: No Plug & Play device found
Non-volatile memory driver v1.3
Linux agpgart interface v0.103
crash memory driver: version 1.1
Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 4 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
brd: module loaded
loop: module loaded
input: Macintosh mouse button emulation as /devices/virtual/input/input2
Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
ohci_hcd 0000:00:06.0: PCI INT A -> Link[LNKB] -> GSI 11 (level, low) -> IRQ 11
ohci_hcd 0000:00:06.0: setting latency timer to 64
ohci_hcd 0000:00:06.0: OHCI Host Controller
ohci_hcd 0000:00:06.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
ohci_hcd 0000:00:06.0: irq 11, io mem 0xf0804000
usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
usb usb1: Product: OHCI Host Controller
usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 2.6.32-642.el6.i686 ohci_hcd
usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:06.0
usb usb1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
hub 1-0:1.0: 12 ports detected
uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
PNP: PS/2 Controller [PNP0303:PS2K,PNP0f03:PS2M] at 0x60,0x64 irq 1,12
serio: i8042 KBD port at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
serio: i8042 AUX port at 0x60,0x64 irq 12
mice: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
rtc_cmos rtc_cmos: rtc core: registered rtc_cmos as rtc0
rtc0: alarms up to one day, 114 bytes nvram
cpuidle: using governor ladder
cpuidle: using governor menu
EFI Variables Facility v0.08 2004-May-17
input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/inpu                                                                                        t3
hrtimer: interrupt took 5130249 ns
usbcore: registered new interface driver hiddev
usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
usbhid: v2.6:USB HID core driver
GRE over IPv4 demultiplexor driver
TCP cubic registered
Initializing XFRM netlink socket
NET: Registered protocol family 17
Using IPI No-Shortcut mode
registered taskstats version 1
rtc_cmos rtc_cmos: setting system clock to 2016-11-12 23:16:37 UTC (1478992597)
Initalizing network drop monitor service
Freeing unused kernel memory: 556k freed
input: ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/i                                                                                        nput4
Write protecting the kernel text: 4616k
Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 1992k
Refined TSC clocksource calibration: 2133.787 MHz.
dracut: dracut-004-409.el6
dracut: rd_NO_LUKS: removing cryptoluks activation
device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
device-mapper: ioctl: 4.33.1-ioctl (2015-8-18) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
udev: starting version 147
ACPI: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A03:00/LNXVIDEO:00/inpu                                                                                        t/input5
dracut: Starting plymouth daemon
dracut: rd_NO_MD: removing MD RAID activation
ata_piix 0000:00:01.1: version 2.13
ata_piix 0000:00:01.1: setting latency timer to 64
scsi0 : ata_piix
scsi1 : ata_piix
ata1: PATA max UDMA/33 cmd 0x1f0 ctl 0x3f6 bmdma 0xd000 irq 14
ata2: PATA max UDMA/33 cmd 0x170 ctl 0x376 bmdma 0xd008 irq 15
ata2.00: ATAPI: VBOX CD-ROM, 1.0, max UDMA/133
ata2.00: configured for UDMA/33
scsi 1:0:0:0: CD-ROM            VBOX     CD-ROM           1.0  PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
ahci 0000:00:0d.0: version 3.0
ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKA] enabled at IRQ 11
ahci 0000:00:0d.0: PCI INT A -> Link[LNKA] -> GSI 11 (level, low) -> IRQ 11
ahci: SSS flag set, parallel bus scan disabled
ahci 0000:00:0d.0: AHCI 0001.0100 32 slots 1 ports 3 Gbps 0x1 impl SATA mode
ahci 0000:00:0d.0: flags: 64bit ncq stag only ccc
ahci 0000:00:0d.0: setting latency timer to 64
scsi2 : ahci
ata3: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m8192@0xf0806000 port 0xf0806100 irq 11
ata3: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
ata3.00: ATA-6: VBOX HARDDISK, 1.0, max UDMA/133
ata3.00: 16777216 sectors, multi 128: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32)
ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      VBOX HARDDISK    1.0  PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
sr0: scsi3-mmc drive: 32x/32x xa/form2 tray
Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
sr 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] 16777216 512-byte logical blocks: (8.58 GB/8.00 GiB)
sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO                                                                                         or FUA
 sda: sda1 sda2
sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
dracut: Scanning devices sda2  for LVM logical volumes vg_vmcentos/lv_swap vg_vm                                                                                        centos/lv_root
dracut: inactive '/dev/vg_vmcentos/lv_root' [6.71 GiB] inherit
dracut: inactive '/dev/vg_vmcentos/lv_swap' [816.00 MiB] inherit
EXT4-fs (dm-0): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
EXT4-fs (dm-0): write access will be enabled during recovery
EXT4-fs (dm-0): recovery complete
EXT4-fs (dm-0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts:
dracut: Mounted root filesystem /dev/mapper/vg_vmcentos-lv_root
dracut: Loading SELinux policy
type=1404 audit(1478992623.097:2): enforcing=1 old_enforcing=0 auid=4294967295 s                                                                                        es=4294967295
SELinux: 2048 avtab hash slots, 306596 rules.
SELinux: 2048 avtab hash slots, 306596 rules.
SELinux:  9 users, 12 roles, 4211 types, 236 bools, 1 sens, 1024 cats
SELinux:  81 classes, 306596 rules
SELinux:  Completing initialization.
SELinux:  Setting up existing superblocks.
SELinux: initialized (dev dm-0, type ext4), uses xattr
SELinux: initialized (dev tmpfs, type tmpfs), uses transition SIDs
SELinux: initialized (dev usbfs, type usbfs), uses genfs_contexts
SELinux: initialized (dev selinuxfs, type selinuxfs), uses genfs_contexts
SELinux: initialized (dev mqueue, type mqueue), uses transition SIDs
SELinux: initialized (dev hugetlbfs, type hugetlbfs), uses transition SIDs
SELinux: initialized (dev devpts, type devpts), uses transition SIDs
SELinux: initialized (dev inotifyfs, type inotifyfs), uses genfs_contexts
SELinux: initialized (dev anon_inodefs, type anon_inodefs), uses genfs_contexts
SELinux: initialized (dev pipefs, type pipefs), uses task SIDs
SELinux: initialized (dev debugfs, type debugfs), uses genfs_contexts
SELinux: initialized (dev sockfs, type sockfs), uses task SIDs
SELinux: initialized (dev devtmpfs, type devtmpfs), uses transition SIDs
SELinux: initialized (dev tmpfs, type tmpfs), uses transition SIDs
SELinux: initialized (dev proc, type proc), uses genfs_contexts
SELinux: initialized (dev bdev, type bdev), uses genfs_contexts
SELinux: initialized (dev rootfs, type rootfs), uses genfs_contexts
SELinux: initialized (dev sysfs, type sysfs), uses genfs_contexts
type=1403 audit(1478992626.528:3): policy loaded auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295
dracut:
dracut: Switching root
udev: starting version 147
sr 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 5
sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
e1000: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - version 7.3.21-k8-NAPI
e1000: Copyright (c) 1999-2006 Intel Corporation.
ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKC] enabled at IRQ 10
PCI: setting IRQ 10 as level-triggered
e1000 0000:00:03.0: PCI INT A -> Link[LNKC] -> GSI 10 (level, low) -> IRQ 10
e1000 0000:00:03.0: setting latency timer to 64
e1000 0000:00:03.0: eth0: (PCI:33MHz:32-bit) 08:00:27:73:e1:52
e1000 0000:00:03.0: eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
Intel ICH 0000:00:05.0: PCI INT A -> Link[LNKA] -> GSI 11 (level, low) -> IRQ 11
Intel ICH 0000:00:05.0: setting latency timer to 64
intel8x0: white list rate for 1028:0177 is 48000
piix4_smbus 0000:00:07.0: SMBus Host Controller at 0x4100, revision 0
EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts:
SELinux: initialized (dev sda1, type ext4), uses xattr
Adding 835580k swap on /dev/mapper/vg_vmcentos-lv_swap.  Priority:-1 extents:1 a                                                                                        cross:835580k
SELinux: initialized (dev binfmt_misc, type binfmt_misc), uses genfs_contexts
NET: Registered protocol family 10
lo: Disabled Privacy Extensions
ip6_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
nf_conntrack version 0.5.0 (16384 buckets, 65536 max)
ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
e1000: eth0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX
ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
eth0: no IPv6 routers present
type=1305 audit(1478992728.035:4): audit_pid=982 old=0 auid=4294967295 ses=42949                                                                                        67295 subj=system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 res=1
lo: Disabled Privacy Extensions
e1000: eth0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX
ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
```

And `/var/log/boot.log` content is:

```
                Welcome to CentOS
Starting udev:                                             [  OK  ]
Setting hostname vmcentos:                                 [  OK  ]
Setting up Logical Volume Management:   2 logical volume(s) in volume group "vg_vmcentos" now active
                                                           [  OK  ]
Checking filesystems
/dev/mapper/vg_vmcentos-lv_root: clean, 18772/440640 files, 227265/1759232 blocks
/dev/sda1: recovering journal
/dev/sda1: clean, 38/128016 files, 50121/512000 blocks
                                                           [  OK  ]
Remounting root filesystem in read-write mode:             [  OK  ]
Mounting local filesystems:                                [  OK  ]
Enabling /etc/fstab swaps:                                 [  OK  ]
Entering non-interactive startup
Starting monitoring for VG vg_vmcentos:   2 logical volume(s) in volume group "vg_vmcentos" monitored
                                                           [  OK  ]
ip6tables: Applying firewall rules:                        [  OK  ]
iptables: Applying firewall rules:                         [  OK  ]
Bringing up loopback interface:                            [  OK  ]
Bringing up interface eth0:  Determining if ip address 192.168.100.12 is already in use for device eth0...
                                                           [  OK  ]
Starting auditd:                                           [  OK  ]
Starting system logger:                                    [  OK  ]
Mounting filesystems:                                      [  OK  ]
Retrigger failed udev events                               [  OK  ]
Starting sshd:                                             [  OK  ]
Starting postfix:                                          [  OK  ]
Starting crond:                                            [  OK  ]
```

Comment: What major & minor version of CentOS? This looks like either 5.x or 6.x to me.

Comment: Please post the output of `sudo chkconfig --list network`.

Comment: @jayhendren its CentOS 6.8, minimal.

Comment: @jayhendren The output is: `network     0:off     1:off     2:on     3:on     4:on     5:on     6:off`

Comment: can you post your `/var/log/boot.log` and `dmesg` output? link to a pastebin or github gist is fine.

Comment: Also, is NetworkManager enabled? `chkconfig --list NetworkManager`

Comment: @jayhendren This is the dmesg output: http://pastebin.com/6BvfxG0M, NetworkManager isn't even installed. Here's boot.log: http://pastebin.com/ZaHDqKR8

Comment: Oh, by the way, I'm using CentOS trough a Virtual Machine (VirtualBox) in Windows 7, I always forget to tell that.

Comment: one other thing, please edit these responses into your question rather than answering directly in comments :)

Comment: @OiciTrap after booting what does `service network status` tell you? That should have the error. If I had to guess, it's starting before something it needs, and once the computer finishes booting it's dependency is up, so the restart works.

Comment: @jayhendren it says:

`Configured devices:
lo eth0
Currently active devices:
lo eth0`

And if I try to ping to my router it says `Destination Host Unreacheable` as always after I reboot the CentOS...

Comment: And again, after a `service network status` I can ping to my router, ping to google, etc...

Comment: bindows 7 firewall blocking ICMP